# SQL - Problema para insertar registro en tabla y Crear tabla nueva

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo agregar un registro a una tabla llamada animals2 y escribir una consulta para generar una nueva tabla con campos de nombre, tipo y país de cada animal mediante la union entre tablas, ademas de organizarlos por países.

Tengo dos tablas una llamada `animals` y la otra `countries` creadas previamente. La tabla nueva se debe llamar animals2.

```
INSERT INTO animals (name, type, country_id)
VALUES ("Slim", "Giraffe", "1");

CREATE TABLE animals2
(
name candy, pop, vova, merlin, bert, slim(size),
type elephant, horse, bear, lion, tiger, giraffe(size),
countries usa, russia, india(size),
primary key(id)
);

SELECT *
FROM animals INNER JOIN animals2 
ON animals.name, animals.type=animals2.name, animals.type;
```

Creo que hay algo que estoy haciendo mal porque me da error y tengo que hacer modificaciones, por eso consulto que me sugeren porque no encuentro que hacer.

Creo que tengo que unir una tabla a otra y generar una nueva o crear una nueva y actualizarla a partir de la unión de las dos.

Comment: SQL es muy genérico ¿Cuál de todos los motores usas? agrega la etiqueta correspondiente.

Comment: MySQL es la base de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para crear una tabla a partir de una consulta puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
select a.name, a.type, c.country
into TablaNueva
from animals a inner join countries c
on a.country_id  = c.id;
```

De esta forma creas una nueva tabla la cual llenas con los datos que obtienes en la consulta que haces.

En este caso se creará la **tabla TablaNueva** con los **campos name**, **type** y **country**.

**Actualización**:

Para el caso específico de **MySQL** puede usar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
Create table TablaNueva as
Select a.name, a.type, c.country
From animals a inner join countries c
on a.country_id = c.id;
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio

Comment: La [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) dice claramente que esa sintaxis no es soportada.